# Using a PSD or an exported jpg for a navigation bar

Tags: html

Lets say I had just made an awesome looking picture I intend to use as a navigation bar. I exported it as a jpg and now I need to make the actual navigation bar.
I originally thought of image mapping but that's like ancient and does not support drop down menu's. I googled around and I still couldn't find an answer. How do I use one photo as my navigation bar?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In my day, we didn't even have fancy "navigation" bars. We had to make do with chalk! On the sidewalk! It was the goats that stank. I miss those days.

Comment: In my day we didn't have sidewalks. We scratched lines in the dirt with our fingernails (we didn't even have sticks to draw with...).

Comment: Ohhh... You were one of em BROOMSTICK BOYS. Get out my yard! Oh, um, what's today?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the technique of [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/); setting your awesome picture as `background-image` for your menu headings, and using `background-position` to display the appropriate part of the picture in each heading.

Getting this to be pixel-perfect may require an amount of experimentation and patience.

Comment: It mostly involves having a plan or a strategy to innovate. Not having seen it, I wonder...